# Div height solution?

Tags: javascript, height, document

I got the following javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sidebar").height( $(document).height() ); 

    });
    </script>
```

This lets me allow to put the height of an div the same as the document size. But at the moment i got an big problem. In my site there are various javascript options which stretch the original document height.

As you could guess the div wont stretch when the document is stretched because the script only runs on load.

Now my question is, if there is an other way to let javascript recalculate the height every time the document size increases or when an javascript is run. I already tried to put the following code behind some javascript code:

```
 $("#sidebar").height( $(document).height() );
```

And some of them did work but most don't. An other solution to this problem other then javascript is also welcome.

Kind regards,

Augus

Comment: why don't you set your div's height to `100%` with **CSS** instead of js then?

Comment: Agreed with @Jmax, much better to do this with CSS.

Comment: Cause somehow 100% doesn't fill the whole page. Even when i bind it to the body tag. (I know weird sh*t)

Answer (score 0):

Far from efficient, however, you could use the the document "resize" event:

```
$(document).resize(function() {
    //re-run code here.
}
```

Using this would most likely not be recommended for the most part - it came in useful for me when generating dynamic backgrounds in a web page, though. Ideally, you'd want to enable your native structure and styles to be able to cope with resizing, but this isn't always easy at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use resize event.

It will be like: $(window).resize($(window).height())

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = function () {
$("#sidebar").height( $(document).height() );
// other stuff you want to do when the window is resized
}
```

You might want to use window.setTimeout to manage how often this is called. IE for one calls it continuously on drag.